# Here I pass a pointer struct stack * sp by value approach then how value get modify in stack code?

Tags: c, pointers, variables, data-structures, stack

In this code I pass struct stack * sp as call by value ,if it pass by value approach then how it gets update the value in functions and if I miss something then help this to find out?

```c
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<conio.h>
         
struct stack{
    int size ;
    int top;
    int * arr;
};//creating structures 

void traversal(struct stack *sp){
    for(int i=0;i<=sp->top;i++){
        printf("%d\n",sp->arr[i]);
    }
}
 
int isEmpty(struct stack* ptr){
    if(ptr->top == -1){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
}
 
int isFull(struct stack* ptr){
    if(ptr->top == ptr->size - 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
 
void push(struct stack* ptr, int val){
    if(isFull(ptr)){
        printf("Stack Overflow! Cannot push %d to the stack\n", val);
    }
    else{
        ptr->top=ptr->top+1;//how it gets update when i pass by value
        ptr->arr[ptr->top] = val;
    }
}
 
int pop(struct stack* ptr){
    if(isEmpty(ptr)){
        printf("Stack Underflow! Cannot pop from the stack\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        int val = ptr->arr[ptr->top];
        ptr->top=ptr->top-1;//ptr pass by value how it gets update 
        return val;
    }
}
 
int main(){
    **struct stack *sp** = (struct stack *) malloc(sizeof(struct stack));//local pointer variable
        sp->size = 10;
        sp->top = -1;
        sp->arr = (int *) malloc(sp->size * sizeof(int));
        printf("Stack has been created successfully\n");
        push(sp,10);//pass by value in push
        push(sp,200);//pass by value in push
        traversal(sp);    
        printf("the %d element from stack is popped\n",pop(sp));
        printf("the %d element from stack is popped\n",pop(sp));
        traversal(sp);
    return 0;
}
```

Now in this code push and pop modify the top and array as I say I passed as a call by value as you see but they are also get modified in the above code but how?

Comment: You only pass the pointer `sp` by value; this does in no way inhibit you from modifying top etc. You seem to confuse this with passing the stack structure itself by value, which would be written `push(*sp, 10);`.

Comment: but , how the top is get modify the code is working fine but i dont understand why the top is modify i pass pointer variable by value ?

Comment: I already answered this by saying "You only pass the pointer `sp` by value". The pointer is a reference to the `struct stack` object, thus you effectively pass the object `*sp` by reference.

Comment: here i pass sp by value ok ! but when i pass sp on push function then the value of sp copy in push function when push is return then it memory got release and lost all changes but but unfortunately this code modify the value i didn't get this why it modifies if only copies of original are goes in push and pop how they able to change sp->top in main ? can you explain in more clearly !

Comment: If you speak of _the value_, you have to think and state _the value_ **of what** you mean.   For example, if you modify `sp->top`, the value of `top` changes, while the value of `sp` stays the same. - If you pass `sp` by value, only `sp` is copied, `sp->anything` is not. Are you even aware that `sp` is only an address?

Comment: struct stack *sp is a local pointer variable which stores the address and when i pass that value in push then it should not modify but int that code it modify the value which is not acceptable i didn,t get this how push and pop work fine in main function if i pass the (struct stack *sp = address) by value ?

Comment: I can't resist the impression that you don't read my answers and just ask essentially the same question again and again. I wrote that you shall not speak of _the value_ without _**of what**_. The value of `ptr` (= `sp`) is not modified in `push`. Modified are the values of `->top` and `->arr`; these elements are not passed by value.

Comment: i respect your answers and your valuable time given to my question i am not able to get it stuck in that problem from a day thank you

Comment: I'm sorry that you're _not able to get it_ - perhaps it could help to read the comments again - at least I think they contain the required information.

Comment: hey i got your point that sp is passed and only its copy was passed  it is not modified only top and arr are passed and modify the values but they are also a part of sp so how they can modify in main i give top = -1 and arr so you mean to say that they are passed as reference thats why top and arr are able to modify  ? if yes then clearly explain now i am very close!

Comment: You are partly right, but _top and arr_ are **not** _a part of sp_; remember that `sp` is only an _address_; _top and arr_ are part of `*sp`, which is clearly different. Yes, `sp` is a reference (= address) of `*sp`.

Comment: ohk so when i do ptr->top that means we are working with address thats why we are able to change top

Comment: now coming to conclusion i have only doubt that struct stack *sp = address of struct stack if i want to modify the members of my struct stack then i want to pass as (&sp) then  i am able to change my members but u r saying we can modify the members but how u should get to know that we can modify it because i pass the local pointer by call by value when value address copy in push function then it modify top ! in main it is -1 but how whenever we have to change the values we have to pass by reference but this code modify top by call by value i don't know why ?

Comment: I already wrote 13 hours ago "The pointer is a reference to the `struct stack` object, thus you effectively pass the object … by reference."

Comment: ohk thanks ! now i got your point thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to contain some errors so let me address those first:

1. in the `main()` function you have declared this `**struct stack *sp** = (struct stack *) malloc(sizeof(struct stack))`. this is wrong and will bring up a error. You seem to want to pass sp by value, the correct way to declare `sp` would be to do `struct stack *sp = (struct stack *) malloc(sizeof(struct stack))`.

You seem to be mainly confused on how the struct that `sp` points to is being modified by the functions that you have made to implement a stack, lets go through `main()` and see what happends.

`main()`:

```
int main(){
    
struct stack *sp = (struct stack *) malloc(sizeof(struct stack));//local pointer variable
       
sp->size = 10;
sp->top = -1;
sp->arr = (int *) malloc(sp->size * sizeof(int));


printf("Stack has been created successfully\n");
 
push(sp,10);//pass by value in push
push(sp,200);//pass by value in push
      
traversal(sp);

printf("the %d element from stack is popped\n",pop(sp));      
printf("the %d element from stack is popped\n",pop(sp));

traversal(sp);

   return 0;
}
```

So i will break down how this works:

First of all in `main()` we have a pointer to a struct of type `struct stack`:

`struct stack *sp = (struct stack *) malloc(sizeof(struct stack));`

This struct has some memory allocated for it and, `sp` stores the address of this struct.

Next in `main()` you store 10 in the member called `size` in the struct that `sp` points to:

`sp->size = 10;`

You also store -1 in the member called `top` in the struct that `sp` points to:

`sp->top = -1;`

Lastly you allocate some memory for the stack in this line, in this case you allocate `40 bytes` for 10 ints:

`sp->arr = (int *) malloc(sp->size * sizeof(int));`

Now moving to the function calls:

you wrote `push(sp,10)`

lets break this down further and take a look at `push()`

`push()`:

```
void push(struct stack* ptr, int val){

        if(isFull(ptr)){
            printf("Stack Overflow! Cannot push %d to the stack\n", val);
        }

        else{
            ptr->top=ptr->top+1;//how it gets update when i pass by value
            ptr->arr[ptr->top] = val;
        }
    }
```

`push()` takes 2 parameters, one is a pointer to a struct, the second is a integer value.

`push(sp,10)`

Now you pass `sp` to the first parameter `struct stack* ptr`, remember sp holds the address of a struct that you allocated memory for in main().

you are now giving this address to `struct stack* ptr` which is a local pointer to the `push()` function. After `push()` ends, `struct stack* ptr` will get destroyed.

With this in mind you are passing `sp` by value since you are not actually passing `sp` itself (address of sp), you are passing the address that `sp` is pointing to/holding into a copy which would be `struct stack* ptr`.

And now since you pass the address of the struct that `sp` is holding/pointing too, this address can be modified.

Comment: thanks i got your point you want to say sp hold the address but just imagine if i not store the address in sp  and i only pass as struct stack * sp in push(sp,10) then how it changes the top.

Comment: if there is no address stored in sp and you pass it to push() as push(sp,10) then your program will crash.

Comment: Im not quite understanding what you are trying to say but if as you said "but just imagine if i not store the address in sp and i only pass" indicates you passing sp without defining it that will bring up an error

Comment: look struct stack * sp is local varible pointer which stores the address of struct stack(value)  and i passed this in push as value not as (&sp) still they change the members of the sp when i send as call by value why it change sp->top and sp->arr and in main function sp->top=-1 if i want to modify the value in main function then i have to pass by reference (&sp) but when i pass code as push(sp,10) then it changes the value

Comment: i only not getting the point that when we have to modify the structures members then we have to pass by reference but in this case call by value approach members value gets change but i dont know how ?

Comment: well sp has been dynamically allocated memory so it can be modified, you think of dynamically allocated memory as global memory meaning it can be accessed anywhere in the program through a pointer. By using malloc() the memory you allocate can be accessed anywhere in the program

Comment: thannks now i got your point if we make pointer then we have to point them a to a valid object sometimes it works but sometimes it not and that happen with me thats why i am stuck now i got your point